# PHP How do you separate your results to echo in two divs of the one page?

Tags: php, sql

I know how to produce results one after another but how do you separate them? So in my sql I'm selecting * from table and limiting it to 4

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table limit 4"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{$rows['id']=$row;}; 
$price = $row['price'];
```

I dont seem to get any result, any suggestions, sorry guys beginner

```
   ...<?php echo $id ?></font></span>
  <h4><?php echo $price ?></h4></div>
  <div class="planFeatures"><ul>
  <li><h1><?php echo $id=2 ?></h1></li>//how do I echo the next id?
  <li><?php echo $price2 ?></li>       //also the next price which id now is also 2
                                       //and so on......
```

How do I display the next increments results in a different area of the same page, within another div?

I do get results if I sql and re-select all over again (and say id=2) but I'm sure there is a better way of doing it because I've already got my 4 results with my limit.

Comment: Run your sql look through an array. Basically during the loop add your results to the array, and then use the array keys later in your code to display the data where you want.

Comment: update you question and add the code for query result too

Comment: GrumptyCrouton som like this $result = $conn->query($sql); while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$rows['id']=$row;
}
?

Comment: im a little lost after here $sql = "SELECT * FROM table limit 4";
$result = $conn->query($sql); while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {$rows['id']=$row;}; I dont seem to get any result, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not saving the results from the query result properly. Each iteration of the loop overwrites the same bucket in the `$rows` array. Instead, you need to add elements to the `$rows` array; this will produce an indexed array. Then you can iterate over it and generate the HTML content.

```
<?php

// Perform query.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table limit 4";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Fetch results
while (true) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if (!$row) {
        break;
    }

    $rows[] = $row;
}

// Generate HTML content using $rows array.
?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row):?>
      <tr>
        <td>ID: <?php print $row['id'];?></td>
        <td>Price: <?php print $row['price'];?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I took some liberty in the above example and generated a simple HTML table. Of course you can modify this to generate whatever you want.

I hope I've interpreted your question accurately, apologies if not!

Comment: Actually I just realised this isnt quite what I meant.

Comment: This gives all four results in the same place, within the same table. I wanted to get the answer in separate places of the page. 
        <td>ID: <?php print $row['id'];?></td>
        <td>Price: <?php print $row['price'];?></td>
      How do I get the second, third and fourth result in other areas of the page and not the same table?

Comment: but thank you for making an effort. Appreciating your knowledge.

Comment: @JamesAda How you generate the output is up to you. The `$rows` variable is an indexed array; this means you can access each result like `$rows[0]`, `$rows[1]`, ETC. If you know how many results there will be I guess you could hardcode this. You can verify the length of the array like so: `if (count($rows) == 4) { /*code*/ }`. You know at most how many results it will have due to the `LIMIT` clause in the query.